# Home page content full screen

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.2.5, home-page, full-width

I am working on **Magento 2.2.5**, where I put an **home page**.

The **html** of the home page is using **bootstrap 4**, to make it responsive an full width. What works well when seeing that html in isolation.

Now, when the **respective html** is put in the **static home page**, using the **admin**, and I see it in the store home page, then it is **not full width**.

This given Mangeto set a maximum width for the container of whole home page content, between the navigation bar and the footer.

The question, is... How can I make the home page content **full width**? without making the **whole site full width**.  The obvious thought is to find the style of the respective container and make it full width, and conditionally just make it for the home page.... but I just can not find the right file to modify.

I am extending the Theme Magento blank.

Any help, or hint about the right phtml or style to overwrite, will be appreciated!